# PHP- PDO - Export Mysql Database to a .SQL file and Save on the server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have written the following code to export all the tables with creating and insert statement into a sql file.

The code doesn't write .sql file and throws an error.Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
  try {
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$tableName  = '*';
$backupFile = 'cms/upload/db/yourtable.sql';
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName");
$stmt->execute();
```

Error returned is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*' at line 1' in

Comment: anything from http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php ?

Comment: and `$tableName  = '*';` is that asterisk just a representation of an actual table name?

Comment: @Fred-ii- asterisk I would like to export all the tables and the data

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried error_reporting(E_ALL);  doesnt show anything on the page nor in the error_log

Comment: TBH, I don't know if `*` is a valid MySQL statement. So, did you apply error handling with both links I gave you? You also need to "display" errors  http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` what about the PDO error checking? could be a file permissions/path issue

Comment: @Fred-ii- I updated the question with the exact error

Comment: `right syntax to use near '*'` there you go; you need to select an actual table name. See the manuals http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html  ---- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/select-into-outfile/

Comment: However, if FROM * is valid syntax, then try using ticks `\`` around the `$tableName` variable in the query.

Comment: What about just dumping the full database? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Far as I know, you need to select from a "table" name. Unsure what you want to do here. Edit: or try what @chris85 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to troubleshoot this query.

First check that the query would work without the 'INTO OUTFILE' statement.

Your code with the current parameters would yield
SELECT * from *

Which would return an error because

1. you cannot specify a wildcard as the table name
2. column names would probably be different from the tables anyway, so another error would occur.

So a way to achieve all of this (backing up all databases) would be

1. use mysqldump.

Or

2. build this into 2 queries and code.

Query 1: SHOW TABLES
(this would give you a list of tables)

Then you would iterate through each row, spcifying a separate file name for each table.

Bear in mind that typically the server might not output to the folder you expect,so I would specify an absolute path to the oufile.

Now to test the INTO OUTFILE output you can use this type of query.

select now() into outfile '/home/username/outfile/test.sql'

This will isolate any issues which could include file permissions, mysql permissions.